# Jsf commandbutton call javascript function then refreshing the whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsf

I have a jsf page and a commandButton inside a form.

```
<h:form>
     ...
    <h:commandButton action="#{mainViewController.showRelatedPayments()}" id="openpay" onclick="openModal();" value="Tst"></h:commandButton>
     ...
</h:form>
```

At the same jsf page i have a modal div..

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                   <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal titles</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                   ....
                   Dynamic content must be here 
                   ....
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

              </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

I have a javascript file also which includes the openModal() function.

```
function openModal() {

      $('#myModal').modal('show');
  }
```

When i click on the button, it calls the javascript function and the modal div shows up but then the page refreshing and the opening modal disappear..

The button also call my backing bean method:

```
public void showRelatedPayments() {
        LOG.info("creating data for page..");
        /*...
           ...
            ...
        */
    }
```

What i would do is click on the button call the backing bean method which create data for the modal content and not refreshing the whole jsf page..

Is this possible? Could anybody please help me?

Comment: you should probably start of by googling for ajax and jsf, I think there are some component / tags that are designed for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<h:commandButton action="#{mainViewController.showRelatedPayments()}" 
    id="openpay" onclick="openModal();" value="Tst" />
```

That code does indeed this:

- Open modal dialog.
- Invoke command button action to load data.
- Reload the whole page.

But you actually want this:

- Invoke command button action to load data.
- Reload only the modal dialog.
- Open modal dialog.

You need to move around the tasks in the desired order and throw in ajax magic to achieve partial page reloads. The `<f:ajax>` is helpful in this.

```
<h:commandButton action="#{mainViewController.showRelatedPayments()}" 
    id="openpay" value="Tst">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":relatedPayments" 
        onevent="function(data) { if (data.status == 'success') openModal(); }" />
</h:commandButton>
```

And add this to the modal dialog's content which should be dynamically updated.

```
<h:panelGroup id="relatedPayments" layout="block">
    ....
    Dynamic content must be here 
    ....
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Thank you. I am doing exactly the same that you told me, but now only the backing bean method invoked.. the javascript method not and the modal not showing up.. could you please help me what is the problem?

Comment: my javascript function now looks like this:  function openModal(data) {
         alert("run");
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
  }   and when i press the button the page reloads i see a flashing but there is no modal.. and there is no alert message.. :(

Comment: <input id="j_idt32:j_idt33:0:openpay" type="submit" name="j_idt32:j_idt33:0:openpay" value="Tst" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action','@form','relatedPayments',{'onevent':if (data.status == 'success') openModal();});return false" />  this is how the generated html looks like.

Comment: I made a mistake in `onevent`, I forgot to wrap it in an anonymous function. See updated answer.

Comment: it's still not showing up.. :( and my web console show an js error at this line in my xhtml... <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>  I'm really don't understand whats happening.. :(

Comment: sorry, now it's working.. i wasn't copied correctly that you wrote.. MANY THANKS! :)